# Move assignment/construct in C++ for class containing reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider

```
 class A
  {
    array<double, 10> array;
    double &a5;

    public:
      A():a5(array.at(5))
      {}

  };
```

It feels like the move assignment or move constructor on this class would make the member `a5` invalid. Is that correct? Is there a workaround?

Comment: This seems like very fragile code regardless of move.

Comment: How do you imagine the implementation of move assignment?

Comment: And why would you want to `move` this? It will be at least as expensive as a copy. `array` is not dynamic and the contents would be cheaper copied than moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid any possibility of `a5` becoming invalid, implement your own move constructor/assignment to copy/move the array content but not change `a5`, eg:

```
class A
{
    std::array<double, 10> arr;
    double &a5;

    A()
      : a5(arr[5])
    {}

    A(const A& src)
      : arr(src.arr), a5(arr[5])
    {}

    A(A&& src)
      : arr(std::move(src.arr)), a5(arr[5])
    {}

    A& operator=(const A& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
            arr = src.arr;
        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(A&& rhs)
    {
        std:swap(arr, src.arr);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have one question regarding the move assignment. why swap? why not simply copy? is there a performance advantage?

Comment: In your example, it doesn't matter, since the array contains `double` values. But in general, it is customary to swap the target members into the temp source object so its destructor will free them after the move is complete. Imagine if your array contained objects instead of numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot..that really  helped.